# fgets seems to "get" \n even after getchar is used

Tags: c, scanf, buffer, fgets

So, I have this code, and then proceed to save "name" into a binary file.

```
scanf("%d", &option);
while(getchar() != '\n');

fgets(name,MAX_SIZE,stdin);
```

I think fgets holds on to that '\n', cause the first word is saved on line 2 of the binary file, and then each word on a new line. However, when I proceed to save something else to another binary file before exiting the loop, the strings get saved consecutively.

How do I get rid of that '\n'? Thanks a lot.

Comment: "line 2 of the binary file" is unclear.  Binary files are usually not thought of having _lines_.  Do you mean a _text_ file?  What are its example contents?

Comment: `fgets(name,MAX_SIZE,stdin);` reads an entirely new line from `stdin` - including the newline.  It doesn't hold on to anything from the previous reads from `stdin`.

Comment: Not enough information to fully answer you question, but please note that `fgets()` does copy the trailing newline character into the string. So if the `while(getchar() != '\n');` was not present, the immediate call to `fgets()` after the `scanf` would have returned a string containing only a newline, effectively inserting an "empty line" into your file, if you were to write to file.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the correct loop for reading to newline also needs to take into account EOF (the last line of input might not end with a newline), so it should be:

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
    ;
```

The code that reads the name should probably be like this, again remembering that there might not be any input left so `fgets()` might indicate EOF:

```
char name[MAX_SIZE];
if (fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin) != NULL)
{
    name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = '\0';
    …write name to binary file…
}
```

There won't be a newline at the start of `name`; there might not be anything `name` if the user simply hit <kbd>return</kbd> instead of typing a name, but you can detect that easily enough.  You might want to remove leading and trailing white space too, and maybe even normalize the white space within the line (ensuring that all sequences of one or more white space characters are replaced by a single blank).

Since you've not shown how you write the data to the 'binary file', it isn't clear that anyone can help you more. If you added the code that writes the data, you would get a more useful answer.  For example, if you use `fprintf(fp, "\n%s\n", name)`, you would get a leading newline, but it is unlikely you'd ask about that.